# Why does Azure lose timezone information in DateTimeOffset fields?

Tags: sql-server, azure, datetimeoffset

We're working on a IOS app using Microsoft's Azure Mobile Services. The web GUI creates date-time as DateTimeOffset fields, which is fine. But when we have the mobile put datetimes into the database, then read them from the database, via Entity Framework, we're seeing them adjusted to UCT. (We see the same thing when we view the records in SSMS.)

I've always been frustrated by the lack of timezone support, in SQL's standard datetime types, and I'd thought that DateTimeOffset would be better. But if I wanted my times in UTC, I'd have stored them in UTC. If a user enters a time as 3:00 AM, CST, I want to know he entered CST. It makes as little sense to me to convert it to UTC, and throw away the offset, as it did to assume that 3:00 AM CST and 3:00 AM PDT were the same.

Is there some kind of database configuration I can do to keep the Azure database from storing the dates in UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that at some point in Azure Mobile Services, the property is converted to a JavaScript `Date` object, which cannot not retain the offset.

There are a couple of blog posts describing this issue, and possible workarounds:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2013/05/13/preserving-date-time-offsets-in-azure-mobile-services/
- http://michele-colombo.it/2014/11/azure-mobileservices-how-to-properly-save-datetimeoffset-with-offset/

Essentially, they both take the same approach of splitting out the offset into a separate field.  However, looking closely at these, they both make a crucial mistake:

```
dto.DateTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

Should actually be:

```
dto.UtcDateTime
```

The `DateTime` of a `DateTimeOffset` will always have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, and thus `ToUniversalTime` will assume the source is *local*, rather than using the offset of the DTO.

There are a few other similar errors I see in the code in these posts, so be careful to test thoroughly.  However, the general approach is sound.

Comment: In our case, we know which timezone each mobile is in, so we can convert the times we receive from UTC to the mobile's timezone. But it seems to me that there is an issue here that MS needs to fix.

Comment: It would be great if you could show a bare-minimum end-to-end demonstration of the problem, from your perspective.  Perhaps on GitHub and link here. Thanks.

Comment: Not really feasible - it's the interaction between an IOS mobile app and the Azure database that's losing the offset.

Comment: @MattJohnson Someone has a bounty on this same question. Feel like copying it over? http://stackoverflow.com/q/42943319/2333499

Comment: @SqlZim - Not the same issue, but I can answer that one there.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a Node.js backend and noticed the same thing with `DATETIMEOFFSET`s read from our SQL Server database being returned in UTC regardless of the offset. Another alternative is to convert the `DATETIMEOFFSET` at the query-level so that it is outputted as a string with the timezone information. The following converts a `DATETIMEOFFSET(0)` field to the ISO8601 format; however, other possible styles can be used as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4):

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), [StartDate], 126) AS [StartDate] FROM [Products];`

The new output is now: `"2016-05-26T00:00:00-06:00"` instead of `"2016-05-26T06:00:00+00:00"`

Of course, this means that the client must serialize the string into their respective format. In iOS, the [`ISO8601`](https://github.com/soffes/ISO8601) library can be used to read the output as either a `NSDateComponents` or `NSDate`.

One benefit of this approach is that any database-level checks or triggers can do date comparisons using the `DATETIMEOFFSET` instead of trying to take into account a separate offset column with a basic `DATETIME`.