# Saving Datetimeoffset on Azure SQL not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, datetimeoffset

I'm having a problem with Azure SQL server, on my local machine I can save a datetimeoffset into the db and the timezone offset is correctly saved like
below

```
2017-03-31 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
```

however on azure is losing the timezone offset, my columns are of datetimeoffset type and I'm getting my datetimeoffset using this `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime` or `DateTimeOffset.Now` but neither way seems to work, is always being saved like the below

```
2017-03-31 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00
```

how can I save the correct DateTimeOffset on Azure SQL server.

**Edit:** I'm using Entity Framework Code First Migration, I just create the entity and assign the DateTimeOffset using any of the line above and then context.SaveChanges().

```
var entity = Mapper.Map<CarSearchForm, CarSearches>(model);
 ctx.CarSearches.Add(entity);
 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

and then automapper profile is like this

```
CreateMap<CarSearchForm, CarSearches>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RequestedDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PickupTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.TimePickup))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DropoffTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.TimePickup));
```

Here is the Model

```
namespace Data.Entities
{
    public class CarSearches
    {
        public int CarSearchesId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PickupPlace { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset PickupDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset PickupTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset DropoffDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset DropoffTime { get; set; }       
        [Required]
        public CarTransmission Transmission { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset RequestedDate { get; set; }        
    }

}
```

[image]
I'm only interested in the RequestedDate property above, I can't figure it out why is not saving the timezone offset on Azure but works locally.

Thanks

Comment: How do use save it to the database? EF? ado.net? For some reason time part is missing from your datetime

Comment: Show code how your save it

Comment: I made an edit, I'm using EF code first migrations, nothing special about it, just create the entity and assing the value and ctx.SaveChanges()

Comment: You're casting it to a `date` somewhere.

Comment: Show us your code first model.

Comment: @SQLMason then why it works locally but not on Azure, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Cameron Model added

Comment: Can you show your table structure.  Sorry, just trying to cover all bases.

Comment: @SQLMason added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... I'm getting my datetimeoffset using this `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime` or `DateTimeOffset.Now`

- The first one is always going to give you a UTC `DateTime` value (offset `+00:00`).  It is equivalent to `DateTime.UtcNow`.
- The second one will give you a `DateTimeOffset` value, whose local time and offset match the computer where it is running.

  - On your local computer, you see `-05:00` because it uses your computer's local time zone setting.
  - On Azure, you see `+00:00`.  This is because most Azure servers and services are set with their time zone to run in UTC.

    In general, this is the [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) for servers, especially those in the cloud.  Servers often need to connect with clients all over the world, and interchange data with each other.  UTC is the only time zone that is sensible.

Another way to think about it is that if a machine's time zone is set to UTC, `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.UtcNow` will give the same date and time values, but one will have its `.Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Local` and the other will have it set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`.   Since `DateTimeOffset` doesn't have a `Kind` (thankfully), one cannot distinguish between `DateTimeOffset.Now` and `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` on a machine whose time zone is set to UTC.

As far as what to do about it - if you desire some other time zone to be taken into account, you'll first have to know which time zone that is.  Then you can use either the `TimeZoneInfo` class (if you're using Windows time zones), or the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library (if you're using IANA time zones) to convert the current UTC time to a `DateTimeOffset` in that particular time zone.

Using `TimeZoneInfo`:

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset easternNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, tz);
```

Using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
DateTimeOffset easternNow = now.InZone(tz).ToDateTimeOffset();
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation about azure timezone and how it works, based on that I get the following, always store datetime on UTC and convert to local datetime manually specifying the Timezone on my application code.

Comment: Yes, precisely.  Consider that your code should exhibit the same behavior and record the same data regardless of where it is hosted or what time zone setting the server happens to be on.